# Why appears a duplicate section cell while-in-search-mode in UITableViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Why appears a duplicate section with one empty cell (or even maybe table) behind my cells that are the results of the search? That dummy cell appears when I'm dragging my real on-top cells to the bottom.

[image]

UPDATE: However, I do not see a duplicate tableView in my xib file:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like duplicate and never happened to me before. Haven't you accidentally  allocated another table view object? What about viewDidLoad or loadView?

Comment: Thanks. However, I do not implement loadView for the table VC. Also, have looked at my viewDidLoad but there are no allocations of custom table VC :( You see, that duplication only happens in search mode (I mean, first I enter search text, then keyboard dismisses after I start to scroll rows). Everything looks fine in default list mode.

Comment: I found the problem: I did tableView realod instead of searchResultsTableView while in search.